# How to make values from input form not disappear after form is submitted using django

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have a html table of variable dimensions in which every cell is

```
<input type = "number">
```

After the user has filled every cell and pressed submit, a result of some calculation should be printed in a `h2` tag. As predicted every time user presses submit the content that was written inside the table is deleted. Is it possible to somewhat negate that so that after the user has pressed submit he gets the result outputted but his input in the table stays where it was? This is html of the template where all of this is happening:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h2> Dimensions: {{ f_number }} X {{ s_number }} </h2>

    <form method = "post" action="/calculated/">{% csrf_token %} 
        <table style = "border: 1px solid black;" border = 1>


        {% for i in range_first %}

            <tr>
            {% for j in range_second %}
                    <td> <input type = "number" name = "{{ i }}{{ j }}"> </td>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>

        {% endfor %}
        </table>

        <input type = "Submit" value = "Calculate" name = "calc">

        {% if result %}
            <h2> The result is: {{ result }}. </h2>
        {% endif %}


    </form>


{% endblock content %}
```

This is my view function:

```
def calculate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        content = request.POST.dict()
        stuff = calculator.MatrixCalculator(content)

        dimensions = stuff.dimensions_to_normal_form()
        array_numbers = stuff.numbers_to_normal_form()

        range_first = range(dimensions[0] + 1)
        range_second = range(dimensions[1] + 1)


        result = stuff.Rank(array_numbers, dimensions)


        return render(request, 'enter_number.html', {'result': result, 
        'f_number': dimensions[0] + 1, 's_number': dimensions[1] + 1, 
        'range_first': range_first, 'range_second': range_second})
```

Comment: You need to share your view function (the one that renders this template) as well. But I would suggest you look into using Django Form classes - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#forms-in-django - rather than try to do everything manually. (Might seem like more boilerplate at first, but it's definitely well worth it in any moderately complex project.)

Comment: To come back to your direct question though, when you submit the form the page gets rerendered. And since you don't give your input any default `value` attributes (since you don't want any when the user first goes to the page), the form is going to come up blank on submission. Using Django forms will make this much easier because you can check if the page is requested with POST and, if so, automatically pass the submitted values in, with just a single call to instantiate the class.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I didn't share the view function because I didn't think it contained anything important for the question at hand, but I will update my question. I've tried doing it with forms at first, but I couldn't manage to do it given that I would have variable number of field, but that is a question for another time. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Actually, it might be better to do this just in Javascript, by having an event handler for the form's `submit` event. It depends what your "calculation" really involves. Even if it involves database queries or something else requiring the server, you could still do it via Ajax. By using JS you avoid reloading the page, which would sidestep this problem altogether.

Comment: @RobinZigmond calculations involes just some math, there is no database. I'll look into  doint it with js but is there no way without it?

Comment: of course you can do this on the server side, as I said above you just need to populate the initial values in the case of form submission, which is easy with Django's Forms framework. But using JS will probably give a better user experience.